# XSLT: How to get ancestor-text content

Tags: xslt

I have the following stylesheet, whcih I created with lots of help from all of you!

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$files">
    <xsl:result-document href="{substring-before(document-uri(), '.xml')}.txt" method="text">
Kuerzel;AT/NT;Stelle;Zitat
<xsl:apply-templates select="//note"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
      
   
   <xsl:template match="//note">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="child::*[1][self::ref[@type='biblical']]">
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*[@type='biblical']/@cRef">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>test;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="ancestor::q[1]"> <!-- this is the part in question -->
                  <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::q[1]"></xsl:value-of>
                  <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

it's supposed to grab the `<q>` before the `<note><ref type="biblical">` in this art of XML:

```
<text><body>
<div><head facs="#facs_13_TextRegion_1624022854326_321">
   <pb facs="#facs_13" xml:id="img_0013" n="4v"/>            
   <lb facs="#facs_13_line_1624022854428_324" n="N001"/>Von dem Menschen vor dem fall.</head>
   <p facs="#facs_13_TextRegion_1624022900738_331">
      <lb facs="#facs_13_line_1624022854429_325" n="N001"/>Gott hat von anfang den Menschen erschaffen
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l4" n="N002"/><note place="margin-left" facs="#facs_13_TextRegion_1624023026742_370">
         <lb facs="#facs_13_r1l1" n="N001"/>Gen. 1.</note>zu seinem Ebenbilde und gleichnuß<note type="annotation">Vgl. <ref type="biblical" cRef="Gn_1,26-27">Gen 1,26f.</ref></note> und in mit
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l5" n="N003"/>gnaden geziert, auch durch die erblich <w>gerechtig<pc>-</pc>
         <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l7" n="N004"/>keit</w> dermassen zugerichtet, das er in allen <w>kreff<pc>-</pc>
            <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l8" n="N005"/>ten</w> deß leibs und der seelen gantz recht were und von <w>kei<pc>-</pc>
               <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l9" n="N006"/>nen</w> bösen unnd unordenlichen bewegungen angefochten
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l10" n="N007"/>wurde, sonder das inn ime das fleisch dem Geist und die
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l11" n="N008"/>understen krefften der seele den obersten (welche allein zu
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l12" n="N009"/>dem guten anweyßten) gehorsam weren.
   </p>
   <p facs="#facs_13_TextRegion_1624022922087_339">
      <lb facs="#facs_13_line_1624022900872_333" n="N001"/>Da nun das<note type="crit_app"><bibl><ref type="bibl" target="#mehlhausen_augsburger_interim"><surname type="editor">Mehlhausen</surname>, Augsburger Interim</ref>, S.&#x00A0;36</bibl>: des.</note> menschen gemüt dermassen wol <w>zuge<pc>-</pc>
         <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l14" n="N002"/><note place="margin-left" facs="#facs_13_TextRegion_1624023026742_369">
            <lb facs="#facs_13_r1l2" n="N001"/>Eccle. 15.</note>richtet</w> was, <q>hat in Gott gelassen inn der hand seines <w>eig<pc>-</pc>
               <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l15" n="N003"/>nen</w> Raths</q><note type="annotation"><ref type="biblical" cRef="Sir_15,14">Sir 15,14</ref>.</note>, Also weyt, das er nicht weniger macht hette
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l16" n="N004"/>zu wölen das gut als das böse.
   </p>
   <p facs="#facs_13_TextRegion_1624022943633_345">
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l17" n="N001"/>Wo sich dann der Mensch diser seiner freiheit recht
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l18" n="N002"/>gebraucht, auch den gebotten, die ime Gott selbs gegeben,
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l19" n="N003"/>gehorsam gewesen were, so hette er die güter und <w>gerechtig<pc>-</pc>
         <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l20" n="N004"/>keit</w>, die er empfangen, ime selbst und allen seinen <w>nachkom<pc>-</pc>
            <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l21" n="N005"/>men</w> erhalten, auch ime und inen nicht gemangelt, <w>frümb<pc>-</pc>
               <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l22" n="N006"/>klich</w> und seligklich zuleben. Es het ine auch weder hunger
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l23" n="N007"/>noch durst, hitz noch kelte, schmertz noch kranckheit noch
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l24" n="N008"/>der todt betrübt oder geengstiget. Besonder het er alle <w>sün<pc>-</pc>
         <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l25" n="N009"/>den</w> und gebrechen gemitten und<note type="crit_app">Fehlt <bibl><ref type="bibl" target="#mehlhausen_augsburger_interim"><surname type="editor">Mehlhausen</surname>, Augsburger Interim</ref>, S.&#x00A0;36</bibl>.</note> von den straffen als <w>be<pc>-</pc>
            <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l26" n="N010"/>lonungen</w> der sünden sich keinerley gefahr weder für sich
      <lb facs="#facs_13_r2l27" n="N011"/>selbst noch seine nachkommen besorgen dürffen.
   </p>
</div>
</body></text>
```

My expected output is something like this:

```
Kuerzel;AT/NT;Stelle;Zitat
Gn_1,26-27;test;Vgl. Gen 1,26f.;
Sir_15,14;test;Sir 15,14.;hat Gott gelassen inn der hand seines...
```

And thus I added the line in question in the template, hoping to resolve this issue that way.
However, It does not seem to work :-/
Alternatively I could probably also look for a substring "Vgl." in the note-element and then go to the `<q>` directly before.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any ancestor relation between the `q` element and the `note` with `ref/@type = 'biblical'`.

Perhaps `preceding::q[1]` is what you are looking for but you make it rather hard for us to help if you don't cut samples to a minimum to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I thank you a lot and of course you are right, I should have cut the example down a lot! 
But as usually, your solution also works! Thank you